# Pass basic authentication without prompting login box from browser in JSP frames

Tags: java, html, jsp, basic-authentication

I have created frame in JSP which takes some site in source which has basic authentication implemented

```
<frameset frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frame name="content" src="http://abc/" marginheight="0" 
       marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
```

but when this frame loads it prompts login box of browser.

What code should be used so that if I provide hardcoded user name and password, each time when I run site within the frame it loads site directly?

Comment: may b i m not clear. i want to get rid of login dialogue produced by browser, by providing its user name and password in html or via java code.
hope em clear now. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an AJAX request with the `Authorization` header having the authentication details, such that further requests join the session and does not need authentication.

Here it is to add the `Authorization` header:

```
byte[] authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user:password".ToCharArray());
String authHeaderValue = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes);
//Add Authorization:authHeaderValue to the request
```

Comment: `String urlString="http://abc";
String username="xyz";
String passwordString="123";

//open url conn
URL url=new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();


//set url conn to get info
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);

//do authorization
byte[] encodedpass=(username+":"+passwordString).getBytes();
sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder=new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoder.encode(encodedpass));
`
i have tried above code, but it still prompts login box..
else i can do??

Comment: Can u please check headers on the browser side, if he is sending the Authorization header for further requests.?   Also verify if the AJAX request is successful, if the login is happening?

Comment: em not getting on how to use ajax request.... its confusing.
wait till i get some tutorial on it

Comment: i tried but unable to do tht
as authentication window still appears...
my req and responses of browser are fine, as it is not sending furthur request. only 1 request was made

Comment: As i was telling you have to make one additional AJAX request before the frame is accessed. I think the frame src is being accessed before the AJAX is called.

Comment: `btoa("user:password")` is less verbose